# Getting Values from Facebook Registration JSON Object

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, foreach

I'm having issues using the Facebook Registration for a contest form I'm building, the form submits and gives me the following JSON array when using print_r:

```
Array (
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [expires] => 1364313600
    [issued_at] => 1364306406
    [oauth_token] => AAAB8bFGZCv4MBAIpl7rSmqzMnJ6V6Om78oZAEvWtxlGZCMoMgiNNIWjLHv2nf7ZAQulTr8fqrwFKFnKROX4rpwbaiZACTMIsrwMZBtDI47jgZDZD
    [registration] => Array (
        [name] => Ben Franklin
        [email] => email@email.com
        [address] => 455 Hickory Rd.
        [city] => Array
            (
                [name] => Baltimore, Maryland
                [id] => 1.04052369632E+14
            )

        [gender] => male
        [birthday] => 07/12/1978
        [phone] => 5550005555
    )

    [registration_metadata] => Array (
        [fields] => [{'name':'name'},
             {'name':'email'},
             {'name':'address', 'description':'Address', 'type':'text'},
             {'name':'city', 'description':'City', 'type':'typeahead', 'categories':['city','country','state_province']},
             {'name':'gender'},
             {'name':'birthday'},
             {'name':'phone', 'description':'Phone Number', 'type':'text'}]
    )

    [user] => Array (
        [country] => us
        [locale] => en_US
    )

    [user_id] => 574207194
)
```

My problem now is I've followed the Facebook PHP example of reading the signed_request as they should to do, which ends in using the print_r to get the output above. Now I need to get some actual variables that I can store in a database. I've been trying to use a foreach loop to get a hold of the fields I need within the Registration array and then the City array inside of that, but to make it simple I was just trying to obtain the [address] value and store it, the following is my PHP code as Facebook suggests and under the print_r command I added my attempt at the foreach loop to get my values, I consistently get errors like "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in....". Anybody have any insight, below is my PHP file processing the submitted form:

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'MY_APP_ID');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'MY_SECRET_ID');

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
     return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if ($_REQUEST) {
   $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                               FACEBOOK_SECRET);
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r ($response);
   echo '</pre>';

  foreach ($response as $r) {
    echo $r["registration"]["address"];
  }

} else {
   echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
}
?>
```

Comment: Fair criticism, but I could still use some help

Comment: Well, you are looping over the whole response array – that means over the elements with the keys `algorithm`, `expires`, `issued_at` etc. one after another. Is each of those a multidimensional array with keys `registration` on first and `address` on second level …? No, they are not. If you want to access an element in an array directly – then why are you trying to use a loop for that …?

Comment: I see, so I didn't actually have to run a loop, I can just access the address variable by doing $response['registration']['address'], very sorry for wasting your time, but thank you for the response